# Fontspec demands ifpdf.sty?

Tags: installing, texlive, fontspec

I am using Arch Linux, but I installed TeX Live from the network, so that I can use `tlmgr` to install a minimal set of packages that I can add to as needed.

Here is a `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Forsan et haec olim meminisse iuvabit.
\end{document}
```

Trying to run XeLaTeX on it gets me:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ifpdf.sty' not found.
```

If I run:

```
tlmgr install ifpdf
```

I get:

```
package ifpdf not present in package repository.
```

I am uncertain how to proceed, and have several related questions:

1. Does `tlmgr` simply fail to install dependencies? I
   installed `fontspec` with no problem.  If it requires `ifpdf` why was this not installed with `fontspec`?
2. Since `ifpdf` seems to be a legitimate package, why is it not installing?
3. Is there some better way I could investigate this problem on my own?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In general TeXLive does not track package dependencies: The recommendation is to install a scheme (or everything; hard disc space is cheap); but this one has been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to find the TeXLive package where a style file is located run

```
voss@shania:~> tlmgr search ifpdf
 iftex - Am I running under pdfTeX, XeTeX or LuaTeX?
 oberdiek - A bundle of packages submitted by Heiko Oberdiek.
```

Install the `oberdiek` bundle to get  `ifpdf`

Use `\listfiles` as first line in your document. Then you'll get a file list at the end of the log file:

```
*File List*
minimal.cls 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
fontspec.sty 2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
expl3.sty 2013/11/19 v4610 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
l3names.sty 2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
etex.sty 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Basic definitions
l3expan.sty 2013/08/17 v4584 L3 Argument expansion
l3tl.sty 2013/09/16 v4592 L3 Token lists
l3seq.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Sequences and stacks
l3int.sty 2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
l3quark.sty 2013/07/21 v4564 L3 Quarks
l3prg.sty 2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Control structures
l3clist.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
l3token.sty 2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
l3prop.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Property lists
l3msg.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
l3file.sty 2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
l3skip.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
l3keys.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
l3fp.sty 2013/11/18 v4601 L3 Floating points
l3box.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty 2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
l3color.sty 2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty 2013/11/18 v4602 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
ifpdf.sty 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
xparse.sty 2013/11/19 v4609 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty 2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fixltx2e.sty 2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty 2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontenc.sty
eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
xetex.def 2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)
fontspec.cfg
t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
***********
```

Comment: Installing `oberdiek` does solve the immediate problem involving `ifpdf.sty`.  However, `tlmgr search ifpdf` returned nothing before I installed `oberdiek`.  Afterwards it returned exactly the "oberdiek" line above. So it seems the `tlmgr search` option only works on installed packages.  Also, I guess it is necessary to just search on ctan.org and try to figure out what package is really needed.  As for `\listfiles` it seems not to work at all yet, and XeLatex is now giving me another error about something missing. But the given problem is solved.